# there is %20 in url using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, multer

I'm trying to make program of file upload using multer in node and express. I have uploaded successfully and also read it but when I using my index for display preview it can't show any image in inspect there is a perfect link but when i click that link and open it contains %20 and that there is no preview of image file

Here is code of app.js

```
      app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
   gfs.files.find().toArray((err,files) => {
    //check if files
    if(!files || files.length === 0 ){
        res.render('index', {files: false});
    }else{
        files.map( file => {
            if(file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png'){
                file.isImage = true;
            }else{
                file.isImage = false;
            }
        });
        //console.log(files);

        res.render('index', {files: files});
    }
});
});
```

and here is my html

```
 <h1 class="text-center display-4 my-4">Mongo file upload</h1>    
        <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="custom-file mb-3">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
                <label for="file" class="custom-file-label">Choose File</label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        </form>
        <hr>
        <% if(files){ %>
            <% files.forEach(function(file){ %>
                <div class="card card-body mb-3">
                    <%  if(file.isImage){ %>
                        <img src="image/ <%= file.filename %>" alt="Image">
                    <% }else{ %>
                        <%= file.filename %>
                    <% } %>
                </div>
            <%  }) %>
        <% }else{ %>
            <p>No files to show</p>
        <% } %>
```

Comment: `%20` is the econding for the space character and it's perfectly fine in URLs, so I guess your problem is somewhere else

Comment: %20 is the way white spaces are displayed inside a url. You have to do url decode if you want to view the white spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%20 is a url-encoded space character.

This line in your html contains that space:

```
<img src="image/ <%= file.filename %>" alt="Image">
                ^
```

Removing that space will likely fix your issue.